# Blinking of Pin upon Updating Position in Azure Map on Xamarin [Android]

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-webview, azure-maps

**Blinking of Pin** while running on android device. Take a look at the gif attached.

I followed this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/master/AzureMapsCodeSamples/Animations/Animate%20along%20a%20path.html) & used **Xamarin Forms** **WebView** for displaying map.
It works fine while running on browser.

[image: Take a look at the gif attached]

Comment: For your arrow layer, did you make sure to set ` ignorePlacement` and `allowOverlap` to true?

Comment: @rbrundritt, yes I set it true for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's what I think it is, this is likely caused by the transition of the labels fading in and do collision detection. There isn't an option exposed to modify this fade in timing currently, but the following workaround appears to work for me.

After the map has loaded (in the ready event callback), add the following line of code:

```
map.map._fadeDuration = 0;
```

This overrides an internal, undocumented setting that the map uses when labels fade in. Using the above removes that delay.